# Impossible to login on Solr using the authentication panel

Tags: solr, jetty

I am applying authentication on SOLR Admin Panel using jetty (I am using solr-6.1.0):

- Added following code in /packaging/j2eemedadm82/m-infra/apps/solr/solr-6.1.0/server/etc/jetty.xml

  ```
  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
           <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
           <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/packaging/j2eemedadm82/m-infra/apps/solr/solr-6.1.0/server/etc</Set>
           <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
       </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  ```
- Added following code in /packaging/j2eemedadm82/m-infra/apps/solr/solr-6.1.0/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

  ```
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>admin</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
     <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  ```

After restarting solr, I can see that an authentication pop up is there:

[image]

- Then I have generated the encrypted password using this command:

  ```
    /soft/jdk_64b/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin/java -cp jetty-util-9.3.8.v20160314.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin admin
  ```

The output was:

```
2021-12-20 14:08:09.004:INFO::main: Logging initialized @86ms
admin
OBF:1u2a1toa1w8v1tok1u30
MD5:21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
CRYPT:adpexzg3FUZAk
```

- Under /packaging/j2eemedadm82/m-infra/apps/solr/solr-6.1.0/server/etc, I have create a realm.properties file to insert the authentication credentials:

  ```
   admin: MD5:21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3, admin
  ```

After restarting solr, when I use the login/pwd to login, it doesn't work as expected. I have no error, but the login pop up appears again.

Is there something that I did wrong ? Maybe the jetty.home variable is not correctly defined in the jetty.xml file.